# Hard drive life time shortening bug

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive

I am big fan of Ubuntu and using that on my desktop. I bought a new laptop and planning to use Ubuntu on it. I saw an article in 2007 saying about hard drive bug when laptop uses advanced power management. I am in a dilemma to whether install Ubuntu or not. Is the bug fixed in the latest version 15.04?

My laptop is: Acer E5-571.

Bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi-support/+bug/59695

https://ubuntudemon.wordpress.com/2007/10/28/laptop-hardrive-killer-bug-how-to-discover-whether-you-are-affected/

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @Rinzwind updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug you posted has "fix released" all over the page. The last release affected by it is "Hardy" so this does not apply to 14.04 LTS nor 14.10 nor 15.04. So *yes this particular bug has been solved*.

By the way: the kernel nowadays handles the "laptop-mode" tools they are referring to.  Nevertheless this will still work as a tool to check the health of your disk:

> First install smartmontools to be able to query your harddrive :
>
> ```
> $ sudo aptitude install smartmontools
> ```
>
> To find your Load_Cycle_Count do this (the last number is the number
>   we are interested in) :
>
> ```
> $ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Load_Cycle_Count
> ```

In my opinion there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents on the issue. The article you posted says:

he following things might cause aggressive power management :

> 1) your (laptop) harddrive firmware might have aggressive power
>   management defaults (operating system independent)

OS independent, related to the hardware, hence Ubuntu has nothing to do with this

> 2)  your (laptop) BIOS might set your harddrive to use aggressive power management (operating system independent)

Same thing as above ^

> 3)   you might have enabled laptop-mode in /etc/default/acpi-support (disabled by default) which will set your harddrive to use aggressive
>   power management

I've looked through that file and there's nothing that I could see that could harm hard drive.

Also, laptop-mode's purpose is to allow the hard drive spin down for longer periods of time. I think the author of that article does not quite understand the purpose of laptop mode.